# How to pass to let a subview UIButton get the press event?

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

I have a view with a tap gesture and  a UIButton on it with its corresponding action.
The problem is that If I press the button its corresponding action is not getting called instead the tap handler is getting called.

I did a hitTest and stopped the gesture-handler from doing anything if the hit was on the button.

But I am unable to let the button's action do something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set your controller class to be the delegate of the UIGestureRecognizer and then implement this method:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
     return [[touch view] isEqual:UIViewThatIsNotYourButton];
}
```

Your hitTest method should actually achieve this, so you might also check if the UIButton is really getting an action assigned to it.